# Красивая подсветка кода

Tags: jquery, style, html, css

На сайте http://ruseller.com есть очень красивая подсветка кода. Хочу перенести ее на свой сайт. Как это можно будет сделать (какие файлы скопировать)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, [по этой ссылке](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/16-free-javascript-code-syntax-highlighters-for-better-programming/) первый пример - то, что вы ищете.

Здесь демо - [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/demo/), можно скачать [тут](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geshi/files/latest/download?source=files).